# Question about damage triggers while going below 0 life

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

My relevant board state is [Blood Hound](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blood%20Hound) and [Shalai and Hallar](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shalai%20and%20Hallar). 
An opponent attacks with unblockable creatures, for say 20 damage, which is more damage than I have life. 
Do I get to add the counters to Blood Hound and then deal damage to an opponent with Shalai and Hallar before I count as being dead and leaving the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Losing the game by having 0 or less life is a state-based action which does not use the stack (CR 704.5):

> 704.5 The state-based actions are as follows:
>
> 704.5a If a player has 0 or less life, that player loses the game.

In a two-player game, you've just lost. In a multiplayer game, CR 800.4 specifies what happens when a player leaves the game. The rule itself is rather long to cover all the possibilities, but the summary is that everything that player owns vanishes from the game with no effect, including any triggers etc which are on the stack.

(Rule references are to the [2023-06-16 Comprehensive Rules](https://media.wizards.com/2023/downloads/MagicCompRules20230616.pdf))

Comment: What about cards that prevent you from losing the game for having 0 life such as Phyrexian Unlife. With that card you can take 20 damage even if it would normally end the game.

Comment: Phyrexian Unlife is not on the board in the OP's question , but yes, you'd take 20 damage, add 20 counters and deal 20 damage to an opponent. This is due to the specific wording of Phyrexian Unlife: it doesn't prevent the damage, just stops you losing the game. Other wordings may interact differently.

Comment: Alright, thanks.
Side question:
If I had Worship in play, how would that affect the damage being counted for the Blood Hound? Would it get counters equal to the damage dealt and then just set my life to 1 afterwards?

Comment: @TGWabba If you have a new question, please ask a new question :)